# rsync permission errors on smbfs share

Tags: rsync, smbfs

I have a nas set up an am trying to rsync files to it. It works fine for file I own

```
$ id dogmatic69 
uid=1000(dogmatic69) gid=1000(dogmatic69) groups=1000(dogmatic69),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),33(www-data),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),111(sambashare),112(admin)
```

The problem files belong to the www-data user

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

**When running there are loads of errors like:**

```
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/some/file": Operation not permitted (1)
```

I have tried setting up the share for both users but still get the issue

```
sudo smbmount //server/development development -o credentials=/home/dogmatic69/.smbpassword,uid=33,gid=33
```

and

```
sudo smbmount //server/development development -o credentials=/home/dogmatic69/.smbpassword,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

all the source files are owned by www-data and have g+rw so the user dogmatic69 can view / edit them.

```
$ ls -al
total 956
drwxrwxr-x 11 www-data www-data   4096 2012-06-21 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root       4096 2012-06-26 11:44 ..
drwxrwxr-x 17 www-data www-data   4096 2012-06-21 14:10 folder1
drwxrwxr-x  7 www-data www-data   4096 2010-10-11 02:24 folder2
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 510649 2011-05-26 20:48 file.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  78792 2011-05-26 20:15 other.html
```

Any idea how I can set this up so there are no errors and possibly keep the owner details correct.

Edit:

The server hosting the files is a linux based NAS, it is a simple box with no ssh and the choice of NFS or SMBFS. I played with NFS but found it pretty crap and a few people said its quite dated.

Comment: more details please...

Comment: more details such as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually pretty simple.. I did some more digging in the rsync options and `rsync -a` combines a few options. One of them being `-O` to maintain the ownership. Note that this option requires rsync being ran with root.

Simply adding sudo to the start of the command and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any options from your rsync command line to set ownership.  Rsync is trying to set permissions and apparently your SMB server doesn't support that functionality.

If `//server/development` is a Windows box, then trying to setup ownership permissions is pretty much never going to work.  If it is a Samba host, then you need to make sure the CIFS UNIX Extensions are enabled on the server, and you need to use `mount.cifs` not `smbmount` if you want to be able to use unix style permissions over SMB.

Comment: Strange that it has no problems when the files are mine. I will try that and see what happens. Edit: no, still the same error and files are in the share are now dogmatic69:user

Comment: changed to $ sudo mount.cifs //server/development development -o credentials=/home/dogmatic69/.smbpassword,uid=33,gid=33 still has errors. From what I read setting uid/gid in the mount sets the permissions for the mounted files not the actual files on the server being mounted?

Comment: Using no ownership options the error changes to "rsync: chgrp file/bah. Permission denied".

Comment: smbmount seems to keep the permissions just fine. rsync just needed sudo in order to do it.